# how to link with a static library in an existing auto make project

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, automake

I have a static library (.a file) that i can link fine with a main program using the following command line on Linux by placing the .a in the current folder and using an include with "" to prefer current folder for library location.

```
gcc userfile.c -L. -lnameoflib
```

However, i needed to integrate this pre-built library into an auto make file project. I have tried adding the userfile.c to the list of source files in Makefile.am. However, when make is ran, **it fails to find references of functions called from the static lib i.e. .a**

Upon some investigation it seems to be *attempting to create a library with the name.a where as the library already exists* and i just want script to **use it**.

The make file project is an existing well known open source project with standard bootstrap, configure, make and make install steps.

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: If you don't want this `.a` to be built by existing makefiles, just add `LDADD = ./libsomething.a` into `Makefile.am` and re-run automake && configure.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped getting through with one issue. I will get back trying this latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want this `.a` to be built by existing makefiles, just add `LDADD = ./libsomething.a` into `Makefile.am` and re-run automake && configure. – keltar